# Unable to mount NTFS external HD

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I have a 1TB Samsung M3 that I mostly use to read files, and not writing. I've always used it as read-only (the standard way OS X will mount NTFS disks) and never had any problem.

However today I had to save a file on it, so I used Paragon NTFS to unmount it. The problem is that after unmounting I can't mount it in any way. I tried using Paragon NTFS, Mounty, Disk Utility and the `mount` command on Terminal. Here are the results:

- Paragon NTFS: It recognizes the disk as unmounted but when I click "mount", the "please wait" window never closes and the disk is never mounted.
- Mounty: It does not even recognizes the disk as the devices list is empty.
- Disk Utility: clicking "mount" does really nothing. The application remains responsive so it's like I didn't click it. And the disk is never mounted.
- mount command: the terminal gets stuck and nothing is returned.

On Ubuntu and Windows 10 I am able to read and write the files with no problems.

By the way it looks like OS X is looking for BOOTMGR on the disk, I have no clue why:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk2s1
journal_replay(/dev/disk2s1) returned 22
** /dev/rdisk2s1 (NO WRITE)
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=32768 cacheSize=1048576K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.30.1).
    Block 2 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
    Block 1953519999 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
volumeType is 0
0000:  eb52 904e 5446 5320 2020 2000 0208 0000       |.R.NTFS.........|
0010:  0000 0000 00f8 0000 3f00 ff00 4000 0000       |................|
0020:  0000 0000 8000 8000 8059 7074 0000 0000       |.........Ypt....|
0030:  0000 0c00 0000 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000       |................|
0040:  f600 0000 0100 0000 635a 7b2c 787b 2c8e       |........cZ..x...|
0050:  0000 0000 fa33 c08e d0bc 007c fb68 c007       |.....3.......h..|
0060:  1f1e 6866 00cb 8816 0e00 6681 3e03 004e       |..hf......f....N|
0070:  5446 5375 15b4 41bb aa55 cd13 720c 81fb       |TFSu..A..U..r...|
0080:  55aa 7506 f7c1 0100 7503 e9dd 001e 83ec       |U.u.....u.......|
0090:  1868 1a00 b448 8a16 0e00 8bf4 161f cd13       |.h...H..........|
00a0:  9f83 c418 9e58 1f72 e13b 060b 0075 dba3       |.....X.r.....u..|
00b0:  0f00 c12e 0f00 041e 5a33 dbb9 0020 2bc8       |........Z3......|
00c0:  66ff 0611 0003 160f 008e c2ff 0616 00e8       |f...............|
00d0:  4b00 2bc8 77ef b800 bbcd 1a66 23c0 752d       |K...w......f..u.|
00e0:  6681 fb54 4350 4175 2481 f902 0172 1e16       |f..TCPAu.....r..|
00f0:  6807 bb16 6870 0e16 6809 0066 5366 5366       |h...hp..h..fSfSf|
0100:  5516 1616 68b8 0166 610e 07cd 1a33 c0bf       |U...h..fa....3..|
0110:  2810 b9d8 0ffc f3aa e95f 0190 9066 601e       |.............f..|
0120:  0666 a111 0066 0306 1c00 1e66 6800 0000       |.f...f.....fh...|
0130:  0066 5006 5368 0100 6810 00b4 428a 160e       |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
0140:  0016 1f8b f4cd 1366 595b 5a66 5966 591f       |.......fY.ZfYfY.|
0150:  0f82 1600 66ff 0611 0003 160f 008e c2ff       |....f...........|
0160:  0e16 0075 bc07 1f66 61c3 a0f8 01e8 0900       |...u...fa.......|
0170:  a0fb 01e8 0300 f4eb fdb4 018b f0ac 3c00       |................|
0180:  7409 b40e bb07 00cd 10eb f2c3 0d0a 4120       |t.............A.|
0190:  6469 736b 2072 6561 6420 6572 726f 7220       |disk.read.error.|
01a0:  6f63 6375 7272 6564 000d 0a42 4f4f 544d       |occurred...BOOTM|
01b0:  4752 2069 7320 6d69 7373 696e 6700 0d0a       |GR.is.missing...|
01c0:  424f 4f54 4d47 5220 6973 2063 6f6d 7072       |BOOTMGR.is.compr|
01d0:  6573 7365 6400 0d0a 5072 6573 7320 4374       |essed...Press.Ct|
01e0:  726c 2b41 6c74 2b44 656c 2074 6f20 7265       |rl.Alt.Del.to.re|
01f0:  7374 6172 740d 0a00 8ca9 bed6 0000 55aa       |start.........U.|
    unknown volume type 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
    total sectors for volume = 1953520001 0x74705981 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
    CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0
```

And:

```
tail -f /var/log/fsck_hfs.log
/dev/rdisk2s1:  alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  sector size = 512 0x200 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  total sectors for volume = 1953520001 0x74705981 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
/dev/rdisk2s1:  CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0
/dev/rdisk2s1: fsck_hfs completed at Sun Apr  1 15:58:34 2018
```

diskutil tests could not be done:

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk2
Unable to verify this whole disk: A GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required (-69773)
diskutil verifyVolume disk2s1
(got stuck)
```

Have tried restarting, switching USB-C port, trying to set the USB device to open on Parallels Desktop with a Windows 10 running (nothing happens when I right click the machine icon > Devices > USB > Samsung M3 Portable, although I've done it before and it used to work). Nothing changed on my machine (no new apps or system upgrades) nor have tried any disk-related processes (such as repartitioning or anything else). Running High Sierra 10.13.2 on a 2017 MBP with an Apple's official USB to USB-C adapter.

I am really out of ideas as of now.